# How extract this date string and convert it to a DateTime using C# and Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

The code below fails to extract the date text and convert it - that's what I've tried so far:

```
var inputText = "some words 2012-01-06 13-32-40 some words";

string pattern = "d{4}-d{2}-d{2} d{4}-d{2}-d{2}";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = regex.Match(inputText);

// it should find the "2012-01-06 13-32-40" text  
DateTime result;
if (match.Success)
{
   result = DateTime.Parse(match.Value);
}
```

How to write the Regex pattern so that the date string part is extracted and how to convert this string to DateTime?

I tried:

```
IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);

result = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss", theCultureInfo);
```

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried? What _exactly_ are you having difficulties with? Please post **more examples** of possible inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Regex pattern would be:

```
"\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d-\d\d-\d\d"
```

Also you would have to parse the date string like this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If the time was formatted like "13:32:40" you could just parse it like you have done it in your example.

Comment: thanks, is there any easy way to convert this to DateTime? Convert.ToDateTime() fails.

Comment: The problem is that you have an uncommon time format. It would work otherwise. However, if your date/time corresponds to a specific culture, you can pass a format provider as second parameter: `Convert.ToDateTime(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"))`